# Cryptographic Service Providers does not prompt for smart card

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have asp.net Encryption and Decryption files project and it is working fine locally when I moved it to the server all functions are working fine except this function which needed in Decryption process:

```
  CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider");
    csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
```

It is not showing this window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On your production server you probably have only one (or no) card reader inserted, therefore you won't be prompted to selected one.

Comment: I have usb token and the driver installed on server

Comment: Ok, but do you have exactly one token and driver installed and plugged in, right? I was saying that if you have exactly one, you will not be prompted so select a card reader.

Comment: Now I noticed that you mentioned this is an ASP.NET application. Where do you expect to see the smart card message? On the server?

Comment: not on the server but in a page that should show the prompt and the page will be accessed online for the others.